# Loading data into a gridview inside the thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagrid, process, dataset

I recently had a need to load data into a gridview in a thread, the problem is that when I try to move content to it, I get an error saying that is not possible, searching the internet I found some solutions how ThreadHelperClass not get more success, if can appreciate if they could help me, thank you now.

the following code:

```
 trediExecucao = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    dataSet = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

                    conn.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    adapter.Dispose();
                    if (dataSet != null && dataSet.Tables != null && dataSet.Tables[0] != null)
                    {
                        dt1.DataSource = dataSet;
                        linhas = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
                        dt1.DataMember = dataSet.Tables[0].TableName;

                        dataSet.Dispose();
                    } 
                    btnExecutar.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
                    rodando = false;
                }));

                trediExecucao.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in a thread?

i do it as follows

```
try
                {
                    using (cn)
                    using (OdbcDataAdapter dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(globals.dgsql, cn))
                    {
                        DataTable table = new DataTable();
                        dadapter.Fill(table);

                        this.MY_DataGridView.DataSource = table;
                        connection.exitcon();
                    }
                }

                catch (OdbcException o)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(o.ToString(), "Error");
                    return;
                }
        }
```

where cn is my connection class and dgsql is the sql used to return the results to MY_DataGridView